# how would I connect with this network path in ruby? I cant get around the C: directory

Tags: ruby

I have a static network path I am trying to navigate to in ruby, how would I navigate to the following path? I cant seem to get around the C: directory

network directory path i need to connect with:

I:\TI

I can get local directories to return true, like this one...

```
# 'test' is a folder in the same directory as the ruby file...
directory = 'test'
puts File.directory?(directory)
# returns 'true'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
directory = 'I:\TI'
```

got it, was a simple answer